# short question to spring mail configuration

Tags: grails, groovy, communication

The spring mail documentation says I have to add the following code:

> Configuration should be done similar to data sources, with XxxMailSender.groovy files under the grails-app/conf directory.

This code:

```
class ProductionMailSender {
    String host="localhost"
    String username="user"
    String password="pass"
}
```

I don't have a file for it, do I have to create it? If yes, which directory?  Is it a groovy script file or a groovy class?
Thanks a lot
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Never used it, but the docs say you save that Groovy class as `ProductionMailSender.groovy` (a new file) inside the `yourapp/grails-app/conf` directory

Comment: ok, makes sense, thanks you. Im so far now. The example code says one line i dont understand tho:   def mailSender = appContext.getBean( "mailSender" )    what does this line do? it throws the following exception groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: appContext for class